# ActionScript 3: Can not Find Uploaded Files

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, actionscript, file-io

This is my first **ActionScript 3** application. It is supposed to **upload data to specific location**, which should be the www root location - the location where upload.php resides.

After I run the ActionScript application, I can select the file and I can see that the data is being uploaded, but **I can never find it**.

Would you be so kind, please, and help me to understand what is going on, and how can I find the uploaded data? I checked both: temporary files location, and the target destination.

*Here is the ActionScript code:*

```
    package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    public class ch30ex2 extends Sprite {
        protected var fileRef:FileReference;
        protected var uploadButton:TestButton;
        protected var tf:TextField;
        protected const YOUR_UPLOAD_URL:String = "http://localhost/Saifa/www/upload.php";

        public function ch30ex2() {
            fileRef = new FileReference();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

            var btn:TestButton;
            btn = new TestButton(100, 25, "Browse...");
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
                fileRef.browse();
            });
            btn.x = btn.y = 20;
            addChild(btn);

            uploadButton = btn = new TestButton(100, 25, "Upload");
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
                fileRef.upload(new URLRequest(YOUR_UPLOAD_URL));
            });
            btn.x = 20; btn.y = 55;
            addChild(btn);

            tf = new TextField();
            tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("_sans", 11, 0);
            tf.multiline = tf.wordWrap = true;
            tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            tf.width = 300; tf.x = 130; tf.y = 58;
            addChild(tf);

            cancelHandler(null);
        }
        protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
            tf.text = fileRef.name;
            uploadButton.mouseEnabled = uploadButton.tabEnabled = true;
            uploadButton.alpha = 1;
        }
        protected function cancelHandler(event:Event):void {
            tf.text = "";
            uploadButton.mouseEnabled = uploadButton.tabEnabled = false;
            uploadButton.alpha = 0.3;
        }
        protected function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            tf.text = "Uploading " + 
                event.bytesLoaded + " / " + event.bytesTotal + "bytes ...";
        }
        protected function errorHandler(event:ErrorEvent):void {
            tf.text = event.text;
        }
        protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            tf.text = "Upload complete!";
        }
    }
}
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
class TestButton extends Sprite {
    public var label:TextField;
    public function TestButton(w:Number, h:Number, labelText:String) {
        graphics.lineStyle(0.5, 0, 0, true);
        graphics.beginFill(0xa0a0a0);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, w, h, 8);
        label = new TextField();
        addChild(label);
        label.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("_sans", 11, 0, true, false,
            false, null, null, "center");
        label.width = w;
        label.height = h;
        label.text = labelText;
        label.y = (h - label.textHeight)/2 - 2;
        buttonMode = true;
        mouseChildren = false;
    }
}
```

*and here is the PHP code, which is supposed to copy the temporary uploaded file:*

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[‘Filedata’][‘tmp_name’], ‘./‘.time().$_FILES[‘Filedata’][‘name’]);
?>
```

*All the code is from [ActionScript Bible](http://actionscriptbible.com/) book*

I would kindly like to ask for the following:

- **What can be the possible sources of my problem?**
- **Looks my code correct? It gets compiled by FlashBuilder without problems**
- **How can I identify source of my issue?**
- **If you would have an example of working ActionScript + PHP application, I would be happy to see it.**

As I spend hours after hours trying various things and combinations, I hope somebody might have had similar problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP statement, there's a weired quote `‘` instead of a simple quote `'`.

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], './'.time().$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
?>
```

I tried with this and it worked fine.

---

Also here's the MXML i used to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
minHeight="600"
minWidth="955"
creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.Button;
        import spark.components.Label;

        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
            ch30ex2();
        }

        protected var fileRef:FileReference;

        protected var uploadButton:Button;

        protected var tf:Label;

        protected const YOUR_UPLOAD_URL:String = "http://127.0.0.1/test/test.php";

        public function ch30ex2():void {
            fileRef = new FileReference();
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
            fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

            var btn:Button;
            btn = new Button();
            btn.label = "Browse...";
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
                fileRef.browse();
            });
            btn.x = btn.y = 20;
            addElement(btn);

            uploadButton = btn = new Button();
            btn.label = "Upload";
            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event):void {
                fileRef.upload(new URLRequest(YOUR_UPLOAD_URL));
            });
            btn.x = 20;
            btn.y = 55;
            addElement(btn);

            tf = new Label();
            tf.width = 300;
            tf.x = 130;
            tf.y = 58;
            addElement(tf);

            cancelHandler(null);
        }

        protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
            tf.text = fileRef.name;
            uploadButton.mouseEnabled = uploadButton.tabEnabled = true;
            uploadButton.alpha = 1;
        }

        protected function cancelHandler(event:Event):void {
            tf.text = "";
            uploadButton.mouseEnabled = uploadButton.tabEnabled = false;
            uploadButton.alpha = 0.3;
        }

        protected function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            tf.text = "Uploading " + event.bytesLoaded + " / " + event.bytesTotal + "bytes ...";
        }

        protected function errorHandler(event:ErrorEvent):void {
            tf.text = event.text;
        }

        protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            tf.text = "Upload complete!";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: +1, this works just fantastically. You helped to solve my problem. For that I thank you very, very much. I am marking this answer as the *Accepted Answer*. I would be glad to know, how did you discover this problem, as I was overlooking it, all the time.

Comment: i'm so glad i could help :) it was not difficult to find the problem : when i put the php script on my php server and browsed to `http://127.0.0.1/test/test.php` i saw the syntax error on the screen.